# Induction motor full load and no load test meaning

Tags: power, power-electronics, induction-motor, induction

Why we doing the full load and no load test for induction motor

What is the purpose ? and can you provide some example?

Why we doing the full load test and find power and stuff

and also for no load test

Comment: If you don't know why you are doing this test then why are you doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by full load you are referring to what is usually known as the "locked rotor" or "blocked rotor" test.

These two tests can be used to get an estimate of motor parameters.

The locked rotor test determines the rotor resistance, and the total leakage reactance, from which stator and rotor leakage reactances can be inferred.

The no load test gives an estimate of core loss and magnetising reactance.

A good explanation is given in the book "Parameter Estimation , Condition Monitoring and Diagnosis of Electrical Machines" by Peter Vas.